# Azure B2C user flow sign in with open Id - Add user automatically

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C, I am using the user flow for sign-in of the user.
For this, I am using the sign-in policy. I have a local account as well as open Id connect as identity providers for this policy.

When the user sign-in with the OpenID connect, if the user is not available in B2C tenant, it asks for sign-up (email verification).

Is there a way, where I can skip this verification and automatically add the user with the email Id and other details I get from the OpenId connect Profile.

Note: OpenId Connect connects with the azure active directory of another B2B tenant.

Answer (score 0):

We do not do a subsequent email verification after logging in with a federated IdP.

However, User Flows will always ask the user to complete their profile when signing in with a federated IdP for the first time. You can use Custom Policy to remove this step entirely and write the account with the data passed from the Federated identity provider - if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you have any reference to understand how to achieve it?

Comment: Use this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=applications) to setup custom policies that mimic the user flow setup you have. In the user journey for the SignInOrSignUp, remove the selfasserted-social step.

Comment: I am already aware of custom policies, but I am interested to know if this is possible using user flow